# Integrating Charged Bodies

Tags: electrostatics, integration, charge

Why is it possible to integrate charged bodies by first taking a small charge and adding more small charges around it?

Wouldn't the similarly charged particles exert an immense amount of force on being brought so close together?

So why don't we account for this repulsive force during the integration process?

Comment: In the integration process, when you take the limit of infinitesimal separation, the effective charge at each point also goes to zero at the same rate.

Comment: It goes to zero but never quite reaches it. But the separation between the charges does become zero.

Comment: No it doesn't. The limit, in both cases, only ever approaches zero. It never reaches zero. This is a general fact about limits.

Comment: So could we also conclude that the potential energy of a point charge is equal to the potential energy of a spherically symmetric body? Would the work done in positioning the former be no less than placing an infinite number of infinitesimally charged particles to form a sphere?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate a charged body"? You can integrate functions, not objects.

Comment: Ohhh. That's why I'm so confused. Okay, thank you.

Comment: Also, there are usually additional internal forces that keep the object together, otherwise, it would fly apart (if the charge density is uniform for instance). But we don't take those into account if we're only studying the electric properties of the object, such as the electric potential energy stored in it.

Comment: What exactly is the reason behind that? When would we actually consider the internal forces? @mrblick

Comment: Usually never in these problems. Another possibility is that you're doing calculations at a particular instant in time, in which case you don't worry about how the charges affect each other in terms of their motion.